# Unable to Create Projects in Django 1.4.2

Tags: django

So I am new to Django and I am going through the tutorials. I tried

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

and

```
python django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

but only a notepad popped up with the following:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

And still I cannot create the "mysite" directory. I already added the `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin` to my Path but no avail. What seems to be the problem? I am using Django 1.4.2, Python 2.7, and Windows Vista.

Comment: What happens when you just type `python` and hit enter from a command shell? It seems like you have .py files associated with Notepad?

Comment: I did that and the Python command line comes up. Tried `import os` and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the file association (since that is currently just a guess on my part) you could  call the absolute path to run it:

```
python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

That should create your project, and from there, you can just work from within the project directory.

You should make sure to add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your PATH. You don't need to add the bin of django.

Comment: Do I have to do that every time I create a new project? I can't short circuit that long thing?

Comment: I made an edit to refer to the Scripts dir instead. But you should check the file associate to make sure .py is associated with python. I think that is what Windows requires, since it does not respect the `#!` bang lines at the start of the file.

Comment: I did that but how do I make sure the `.py` associates with Python?

Comment: @SinnerShanky explains it in the other answer. But right click on any .py file -> properties -> Opens With. Then point it at `C:\Python\python.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Your .py files are set to be open with notepad. Here's what you need to do:

Right click any python file ending with the extension .py
click on properties
In the opens with section, you should be able to see notepad. click on the change button next to this.
click "browse" and locate your python.exe executable, most probably in c:\pythonxx\ directory then click on "open" then "ok"
That should set you up, or you can always revert back for clarifications.